# postDelayed sometime doesn't run in Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, handler

I am running multiple thread and Handler in my code.

And this is my Handler

```
PrizeRunnable mTempPotionRunnable = new PrizeRunnable(aaa);
handler.postDelayed(mTempPotionRunnable, 4000);
```

and

```
        class PrizeRunnable implements Runnable {
        String type;

        PrizeRunnable(String type) { 
            this.type = type; 
        }

        public void run() {
            synchronized (this) {
                  if(!mIsHandlerStarted){
                      if(type.equals(aaa))
                          // Do something
                      else if(type.equals(bbb))
                          // Do something

                    mIsHandlerStarted = true;
                    handler.removeCallbacks(this);
                  }
              }
        }
    }
```

But sometime it run simultaneously.

i don not know the reason.

**UPDATED**

I try to change it to:

```
handler.postDelayed(mTempPotionRunnable, 4000);
```

and

```
Runnable mTempPotionRunnable = new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
      synchronized (this) {
          if(!mIsHandlerStarted){
                // Do something
                mIsHandlerStarted = true;
                handler.removeCallbacks(mMetalRunnable);
          }
      }
}
};
```

May be it resolve my problems. I am testing this method.

But i can't pass parameter to my `Runnable` . How can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make global variable and i can pass parameter to my `Runnable`

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that it's because you're synchronizing on the current instance:

```
synchronized (this) {
    ...
}
```

so unless you pass the same instance to all the handlers each one will use a different lock object. Try a static lock instead:

```
class PrizeRunnable implements Runnable {
    String type;
    private static final Object lock = new Object();

    PrizeRunnable(String type) { 
        this.type = type; 
    }

    public void run() {
        synchronized (lock) {
              if(!mIsHandlerStarted){
                  if(type.equals(aaa))
                      // Do something
                  else if(type.equals(bbb))
                      // Do something

                mIsHandlerStarted = true;
                handler.removeCallbacks(this);
              }
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, "The field lock cannot be declared static in a non-static inner type, unless initialized with a constant expression" so that i remove static, but sometime it still run simultaneously

Comment: @ZuzooVn: Because if you remove static then it's the same as your initial case. Can you make class `PrizeRunnable` static?